# jQuery-File-Upload how to avoid cleaning input file

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I would like to use jQuery-File-Upload plugin only for crop and preview image which I want to upload, but real uploading I would like to make during sending whole form to my php server. Currently jQuery-File-Upload plugin delete selected file from "input[type=file]" and when I send whole form to server file is not sending. How to turn off this "cleaning" in jQuery-File-Upload plugin?

UPDATE:

I found solution: `replaceFileInput: false`

Comment: If you are not going to use the jQuery File Upload plugin for actually uploading the file, then why use it? There are plenty of other ways to preview and manipulate the image before upload.

Comment: Do know any recomendable script for this?

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer to your question, so others with the same question can see it?